# Unknown framework used in PHP web app

Tags: php, frameworks

The framework has MVC design pattern, but it has some weird lines of code. I'll snip a piece of code, does anyone know this weird framework?

```
class pjAdmin extends pjAppController
{
    public $defaultUser = 'admin_user';

    public $requireLogin = true;

    public function __construct($requireLogin=null)
    {
        $this->setLayout('pjActionAdmin');

        if (!is_null($requireLogin) && is_bool($requireLogin))
        {
            $this->requireLogin = $requireLogin;
        }

        if ($this->requireLogin)
        {
            if (!$this->isLoged() && !in_array(@$_GET['action'], array('pjActionLogin', 'pjActionForgot', 'pjActionPreview')))
            {
                pjUtil::redirect($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?controller=pjAdmin&action=pjActionLogin");
            }
        }
    }
```

If anyone knows this framework, can they tell me how to configure it to work on a localhost server? I am using Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pjToolkit. 2sek google

Comment: What is "weired" about those lines? This is perfectly normal php...

Comment: @jeroen How do you want to learn code dialect and a "framework" if not by installing and playing with it?

Comment: @jeroen The OP obviously steps into an existing situation, the framework is already used. What good is "check its reputation" there? You take the stuff you find and dive into it. You do that by locally installing (safe enough for a web application framework, probably _not_ for real software). You may prefer a virtual machine for that, sure. But in the end you have to dive into it.

Comment: it's also OOP, you should look up that term

Comment: Thanks for all @jeroen  just for learning purpose :)

Comment: @arkascha I just know CI_controller I don't know pjAppcontroller

Comment: @arkascha I guess you're right, I'm probably just being paranoid :-)